# Disable access to GeoNode resources per default

Tags: security, configuration, geonode

I am testing [`GeoNode`](http://geonode.org/) for geodata storage. Now I face the problem, that per default some pages are viewable by unauthorized users, especially all registered users with additional details, all registered groups, etc.

I want to disable this and found the parameter [`LOCKDOWN_GEONODE`](http://geonode.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/developers/settings.html#lockdown-geonode) in the documentation. Other parameters from this document I can set in my local_settings.py file, but this parameter won't go effective when I put it at the end of this file: `LOCKDOWN_GEONODE = True`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another place to put this information?
Or is there probably another way to achieve the same?

Comment: Which version of GeoNode do you have?

Comment: I installed 2.4b25 from the testing channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: It was a bug and my pull request to fix it was merged. Until it appears in next release, You can move

```
if LOCKDOWN_GEONODE:
  MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES + \
    ('geonode.security.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',)
```

after local_settings import in *settings.py* file. Like in [this commit](https://github.com/Froggiewalker/geonode/commit/17b6b21d9854f153702996149365f351f7110a75).

---

**Original answer:**

I solved this issue by changing this parameter directly in *geonode/settings.py*.

```
LOCKDOWN_GEONODE = True
```

It might be a bug. [I reported it](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/issues/2277).

Comment: That sounds promising. Still, I am unable to test as I moved to geonetwork in the meantime for now, as I had other troubles with configuration too. Maybe someone else can confirm this as well.

Comment: I would be happy if You accept my answer. It can be considered confirmed as my commit is accepted by GeoNode developers.